# How to catch the name of a function that creates an instance of a class?

Tags: python, function, class

I have been using this so far to get the name of a function that is being called:

```
functionId = sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name
```

However, if I am using a class, things get a bit complicated. For example, I have the following class that is supposed to return a message that has the caller functions name in it:

```
def myFunction():
    # Set the footprint at the start of each function.
    debug = verbose.debugMessage(verbosityState)
    debug.setFunctionFootprint()

    # The rest of the function.
    debug.verbosity(1, "This is just a plain info message.")
```

As you can see, I am creating an instance of my debug class and the first thing I do is, I pass a variable into the class. However, in order to activate the function name extraction process, I need to call a method for that, this bit: `debug.setFunctionFootprint()`

Then the message will have `myFunction` in it. But, is there a more elegant way to do that? Without actually needing to call a method?

Also, another problem is, once I create my `debug` instance, the function name is set, in order to re-use it in another function, I need to call that method again.

Comment: Ok, I do not understand why this has been down-voted. Any help on that as well?

Comment: I think the reason you're getting downvoted is mostly because it seems like you're doing something you oughtn't. What's the end goal here? Why do you need to know the method name? If something is going wrong, you'd be much better off making your program throw an error as soon as possible (like within `__init__` in this case). The stack trace will then tell you where it happened.

Comment: Hi jpmc26, well, I am trying to make my debug class understand the name of the function that has created it, so that it can include the name, for example, inside a message printed: `[00:58:24.556999] {myFunction} {verboseTest.py} | (INFO) This is just a plain info message.`

Comment: I think you're going overboard with the logging, then. Logging isn't free; disk writes are expensive. What are you planning to do with this information once you have it?

Comment: @jpmc26 Just display it on the screen for now. I am creating my own debugging class in which I have wrapped up some verbosity level checks, various message templates etc. Something to help me debug as my python script runs. Nothing fancy, and it works so far, just that problem I have described above :) Thanks by the way.

Comment: Is there something built-in [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) doesn't do that you need?

Comment: @HuuNguyen Thanks, I will look into that. However, might be a bit of an overkill for what I am trying to do. Besides, I am trying to improve my class / object skills by creating my own class, and thought it would be nice to wrap some of my simple debugging functions I used before into a class and keep it tidy.

Comment: Actually, after looking into the built in logging, I decided that it should do the job and there is no point for re inventing the wheel. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The built in logging module for Python will provide the functionality needed to solve this problem.

```
import logging

def myFunction():
    logger = logger.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("This is just a plain info message.")
    logger.debug("This is a debug message")
```

The verbosity level can be controlled so that "info" messages are displayed but "debug" messages are displayed only if a certain verbosity level is met through the  `level=logging.INFO`  parameters. Please refer to the [Official Python Logging Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) for further details.

Thanks for all the answers and for the help.